# MVC6 - data query with stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using a stored procedure to get data to populate 4 different razor pages.  I only want to use the query once and refresh the 4 pages with different data from the same query.  The data is returned in 1 model. Is there someway to do a refresh on all at the same time?  Is it possible with a view component?

edit:

I am binding the cshtml page to the model as is usual in MVC:

```
@model IEnumerable<_Data.Models.KPI>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.KPI1)
}
```

I am trying to minimize database queries.  Caching has been suggested as well as SignalR.   I will look into those.  Thanks.

Comment: [Why is "is it possible" not a great question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270933/215552)

Comment: Lots of things are possible.  What have you tried and what isn't working?  How are these pages related and how are they being loaded?  How are you currently populating them with data and how specifically do you want to change that approach?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't update them all and obtain the expected results without pushing information from the server-side by using something like SignalR. It looks like you're trying to minimize your database queries, for which I would recommend caching. Here's a good link to walk you through setting up the architecture. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477235.aspx

If the results are user-specific, you can also try storing the data in session, which requires less work but isn't as best-practice-y, though that can only be done in the assembly with MVC. If you've broken your application into layers, you'll still have to pass that object to your front-end assembly.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I will try read up on SignalR and caching.  I am trying to minimize the database queries.  I can break it up if it doesn't make sense to get all the data at once.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to pass your model back into your server-side Post method. If the data is populated and the event that sent you there is a page button, then you can track the page number you are wanting to display and then send that data back.

I would have an object in the Model that holds the display data (so you're duplicating a bit), and in the post event populate it with a linq statement...

```
Model.DisplayData = SourceData.Select(x).Skip(Model.PageNumber * Model.ItemsPerPage)
```

I'm at work and can't provide a better example right this moment, but this could get you started (I'll add an example this evening when I get home).

This prevents you having to do some funky things in jQuery with data management and also stops your database query and avoids session storage, AND keeps your data strongly-typed.